# isolated Ground

Tags: power-supply, ground, isolation, gate-driving, ground-loop

[image]I have a question regarding the ground connection of two isolated DC-DC converters.

Is the connection advisable considering ground loops? Does it affect the safety?

It is about the circuit seen below. Two transceivers communicating with each other and are powered from two different power sources, the reason for this is that the transceiver on the right is on a gate driver board. The supply of both transceivers via two isolated DC-DC converters is not changeable.

Comment: It depends. What is the ground connection like, and how much current is flowing through it?

Comment: Who knows, you could use isolated transceivers for the same reason you are using isolated DC/DC converts.

Comment: Does the communications NEED a common ground? is it eg voltage level, current loop, opto coupled etc ?